# comparing dates with momentJs

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

This Meteor server code tries to find if a given date string DD/MM/YYYY is within the last 14 days or not.

```js
  let date = '03/05/2017'; //DD/MM/YYYY

  let dayStart = moment().subtract(14, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');

  if (moment(date).isBefore(dayStart)) {
    console.log('before');
   } else {
    console.log('after');
  }
```

This works but I get console error:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Any suggestion how to fix it so it works without the error? thx

Comment: The link in the warning message tells you exactly what to do. You need to specify the format you're using when constructing the date in the `if` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're computing a date, writing that to a String, parsing that same date out of a String in an unspecified (at parse time) nonstandard format, and comparing that to another date in an unspecified nonstandard format.

Instead, [pass a parse format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and do the comparison with Moments, not strings:

```
let date = '03/05/2017'; //DD/MM/YYYY
let dateAsMoment = moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');  // specified parsed date

let dayStart = moment().subtract(14, 'days');  // 14 days before now, as a Moment

if (dateAsMoment.isBefore(dayStart)) {
  console.log('before');
} else {
  console.log('after');
}
```